# How can I solve connection by database?

Tags: c#

> System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException: 'One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> BackEnds.Producte: : EntityType 'Producte' has no key defined.

I get this error when I connect to the database, could you explain where I'm making a mistake?

Comment: private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (NorthwindContext context = new NorthwindContext())
            {
                dgwProduct.DataSource = context.Products.ToList();
            }
        }

Comment: What dose your `Producte` table in the database and class in C# look like? The error is pretty clear : that table / entity doesn't have a key - and it **must have** a primary key for Entity Framework to be able to use it / track it ....

Answer (score 1):

Without an example of your code and the definitions of your entities, nobody will be able to help.  My educated guess (based on the error message) is that the Producte entity has no key defined.

Try to decorate the property of the entity that holds the key with the Key attribute, like this:

```cs
public class Producte
{ 
   [Key]
   public Guid Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;
}
```

Comment: Or if you name your property `Id` or `(entity)Id` (here: `ProducteId`), then it will automatically be recognized as key property. But adding `[Key]` explicitly can't hurt - and it's a lot more obvious than relying on naming conventions, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Try by decorating the Identity Column property like for example "**ProductID**" of the entity "**Producte**" with an attribute "**[key]**".

Ex.

```
    [key]
    public int ProductID {get;set;}
```

refer [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-annotations?redirectedfrom=MSDN#Key)

Comment: friends thank you, I solved the problem, but the data in the database did not come to datagridwieve, only the table came, how do I solve this